# Mismatched Address of SSL certificate

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am adding https header by creating self-signed certificate to web application.

host on IIS 7.0 on Windows server 2008 R2 standard.

I am getting error on browser as Mismatched Address of SSL certificate on web browser.

I have SSL setting required to true.

Plz give any suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name mismatch error indicates that the common name (domain name) in the SSL certificate doesn't match the address that is in the address bar of the browser.

For example, if the certificate is for www.abc.com and you access the site without the "www" (https://abc.com), you will get this SSL certificate name error.

I think you entered wrong domain at the time of purchasing domain certificate . Make sure both URL and certificate for Domain should be same .