# SSL Certificate throwing Error

Tags: ssl-certificate, load-balancing

I got DNS Name (Example : www.MyWebsite.com) supporting HTTPS protocol installed in 2 server (Server A as primary and Server B as Secondary) with Load balancer .

**Scenario :** 
I have installed two different SSL Certificates generated from CA (I have provided same info to get them generated). SSL1 is installed on Primary and SSL2 installed on Secondary. When Load balancer works on Primary web site is running and no certificate Error

When i turn off primary and secondary up and working, load balancer auto switches to secondary and my site is working, However its throwing SSL Error saying "Mismatched Address" -

**details**

```
The security Certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website address. 

This problem might indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to server.

We recommend that you close this webpage.
```

I heard we need to install the same certificate no matter on how many server we install same web app. Is this true?

How can i solve my problem?

Just now i have check someone asking same question [Mismatched Address of SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084341/mismatched-address-of-ssl-certificate)
But i have entered the same domain name which i have provided in purchasing the certificate.

Does it solve my problem?

Any help would be appriciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this by removing previous all certificates from Secondary and exported the primary certificate to secondary.

tested this by turning off primary and secondary being running. URL works fine with no Security error this time.

The funda may be : One SSL Certificate per DNS, not certifiate per Server.

Hope this might help someone.